# Custom ViewPager - Views not showing

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm extending `ViewPager` in my app.
I set up the adapter as well, and verified that `instantiateItem` runs.
The problem is that I can't see anything. Using the dev settings I found out that my class do take up space, which is why I'm guessing there is a problem with the creation of the pages.

### Constructor

```
public CalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    
    mContext = context;
    
    mTodayCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mTodayCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
    mTodayCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    
    this.setAdapter(new MonthPagerAdapter());
    this.setCurrentItem(1);
    this.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

And here's my `instantiateItem` implementation:

```
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Log.i("ViewPager-instantiateItem()", "runs!");
        mTodayCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        mTodayCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        mTodayCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
        
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            mTodayCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTodayCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            break;
        }

        View mCalView = getCalendar();
        
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(mCalView, position);

        return mCalView;
    }
```

`getCalendar()` is a function that returns the view of the calendar (a `LinearLayout`). I know  that it works for sure.

***If so, what else could possibly be the problem?***